Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. Prove that $\frac{1}{p_{n+2}} + \frac{1}{p_{n+1}} > \frac{1}{p_n}$.
Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. It is apparent that $\frac{1}{p_{n+2}} + \frac{1}{p_{n+1}} > \frac{1}{p_n}$ for all  $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ But I have not seen a proof of this.
Is there an elementary proof of this? It doesn't follow from Bertrand's Postulate. Does is follow from the Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture combined with something like Muirhead's inequality or Karamata's inequality? Does it follow from any of these non-asymptotic bounds on prime numbers?

Yes, it follows from those non-asymptotic bounds.

Might be interesting to find the largest $k$ such that $\frac{1}{p_{n+k}} + \frac{1}{p_{n+k+1}} > \frac{1}{p_n}\quad \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N}$ or just for large enough $n$.

@martycohen Heuristically, the largest such $k \approx n - \pi(n)$

I would start from this:

So for $p_n\ge25$:
$$p_{n+1}<\frac65p_n, \space p_{n+2}<\frac65p_{n+1}<\frac{36}{25}p_n$$
$$\frac1{p_{n+2}}+\frac1{p_{n+1}}>\frac{25}{36p_n}+\frac{5}{6p_n}=\frac{55}{36p_n}>\frac1{p_n}$$
A small number of cases where $p_n\lt25$ can be verified manually.
